# Why is query folding disabled in Power Query after adding a computed column using coalesce operator?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI desktop, I pulled some columns off a SQL Server table in Import mode. During transformation, there are 2 columns using which I want to build a third computed column: something like `isnull(col1,col2) as 'col3'` if I had to write it in SQL. But problem is that query folding is **lost at this step**.

I added a custom step in my power query as follows:

`= Table.AddColumn(#"PreviousStep", "col3", each [col1] ?? [col2])`

All columns are from same query/table. I expected the query to fold, but it does not. Please could someone help me understand why?
Kindly note, that I can't touch the source database, hence can't create any views for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Why that particular M expression breaks folding, I don't know.  But you can always work around this by using [Native Query Folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/native-query-folding) with Value.NativeQuery.  EG

```
let 
    Query = "select *, coalesce(OrderDate,ShipDate) ShipOrOrderDate from Sales.SalesOrderHeader", 
    Source = Sql.Database("office", "AdventureWorks2017"), 
    Data = Value.NativeQuery(Source,Query,null,[EnableFolding=true]),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Data, each [TotalDue] > 472.3108) 
in 
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

The Table.SelectRows will be folded into SQL

```
select [_].[SalesOrderID],
    [_].[RevisionNumber],
    [_].[OrderDate],
    [_].[DueDate],
    [_].[ShipDate],
    [_].[Status],
    [_].[OnlineOrderFlag],
    [_].[SalesOrderNumber],
    [_].[PurchaseOrderNumber],
    [_].[AccountNumber],
    [_].[CustomerID],
    [_].[SalesPersonID],
    [_].[TerritoryID],
    [_].[BillToAddressID],
    [_].[ShipToAddressID],
    [_].[ShipMethodID],
    [_].[CreditCardID],
    [_].[CreditCardApprovalCode],
    [_].[CurrencyRateID],
    [_].[SubTotal],
    [_].[TaxAmt],
    [_].[Freight],
    [_].[TotalDue],
    [_].[Comment],
    [_].[rowguid],
    [_].[ModifiedDate],
    [_].[ShipOrOrderDate]
from 
(
    select *, coalesce(OrderDate,ShipDate) ShipOrOrderDate from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
) as [_]
where [_].[TotalDue] > 4.723108E+002
```